# Downloading Image only for visible row in List View

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, download

I have a customized List and each row showing image and text and image has to be downloaded from server.

So I have customized my adaptor and in that getView method i have started a asyn task for downlaoding the image.

But problem is that if there are 50 items in list then if i scroll from 1st to 50 th item in list at one go,

then for each row it will start downloading images regardless of thin that row is even not shown...

so what could be the solution for this???

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a well known problem. Read [Lazy Image Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) and find similar issues. This is not so obvious problem specially when you add convertView usage etc.

A quick workaround for you - I would suggest downloading images on ThreadExecutor with for example max 4 threads and cancel all tasks which are not needed any more. When you use convertView - you can attach a task to a view with setTag(asyncTask) and cancel it when new one is comming. You could also use LRU cache to store some images and not to load them every time you scroll your list.

Answer (score -1):

getView is only called for visible rows.  So if you start the download there, it will only download views that are shown.  Note:  do not ever call getView of an adaptor yourself, you'll cause the listView major problems.

Comment: I guess i have not understood your solution.... please help me with that....As i am scrolling through , every ro is being visible to us so get view should be called and downloading should start on it.....so if go to 50th item then ......

Comment: Well, if you're scrolling through you're going to set off each row as it becomes visible.  That's expected behavior.  If you aren't scrolling then you won't set off those requests.  This is expected behavior-  as you're scrolling you would want to get those images, wouldn't you?  If your problem is that the old requests are still there, you need to rearchitect to use a background thread (instead of async tasks) to do the downloading, and have it skip requests if the position is not visible when it gets around to processing it.

Comment: Yes now i have understood clearly, i guess there is now API in listview.isRowVisible.....there are API for first and last row visibiity.... so

is this a good way 

startDownloadingImage(){

sleep thread for 1 sec
check if thisRow lies between firts visible row and last visible row
if yes --> start Download
else nothing....

Please suggest if any better way

THanks

Comment: Yes.  The first is at getFirstVisiblePosition(), then you can get the number of visible positions with getChildCount()